# How to fix Rest Login API Symfony 4?

Tags: angular, symfony

I realized this api for freelance user authentication. When I test with postman it gives me all the users

```
/**
     *
     * @Rest\Get("/login/freelance")
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getfreelance(Request $request)
    {
        $loginf = new Search();
        $loginf->setPassword($request->get('password'));
        $loginf->setEmail($request->get('email'));
        $freelances = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Freelance::class)->findAllVisibleQuery($loginf);
        return $this->handleView($this->view($freelances));
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more readable.

Comment: what is the code in findAllVisibleQuery in your repository?